# Do I use break or continue in my bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that gathers info on our AWS users. It lists the user name, the accounts (with account number) that he is in, the groups he belongs to and the roles he has access to (if any).

I use 4 levels of while loops to achieve this.

I grab an array of the user groups he belongs to in an AWS account and all the roles in the AWS account (you have to do some gymnastics to parse the contents of the role that I've largely worked out).

But if the array has an empty (or null) member of the array, I want it to continue the outer role that reads the group names.

I build the arrays like this:

```
readarray aws_groups < <(aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Groups[].GroupName')
readarray aws_roles < <(aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName')
```

My questions are, if I use 'break' do I break out of only the if/then statement that has this info:

```
 if [[ -n "$aws_group" ]]; then
             echo "Null group."
             echo "*****BREAK HERE******"
             break
   fi
```

Or, when I use break am I breaking out of the out of the loop that it belongs to that iterates over the aws_group value:

```
while IFS= read -r aws_group
        do
          if [[ -n "$aws_group" ]]; then
             echo "Null group."
             echo "*****BREAK HERE******"
             break
          fi
```

Here is just enough of my code that I hope helps to show the structure I'm using to loop through the aws user names, aws accounts & account numbers, aws groups, and aws roles:

```
while IFS= read -r aws_user_name
  do
    echo "*************************************************************************"
    echo "*        Search for AWS User: $aws_user_name in All KPMG Accounts       *"
    echo "*************************************************************************"
    echo
    while IFS= read -r aws_key && read -ru 3 aws_account_num
    do
      user_lives_here=$(aws iam get-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.User.UserName')
      if [[ -n "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
        readarray aws_groups < <(aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Groups[].GroupName')
        readarray aws_roles < <(aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName')
        while IFS= read -r aws_group
        do
          if [[ -n "$aws_group" ]]; then
             echo "Null group."
             echo "*****BREAK HERE******"
             break
          fi
          while IFS= read -r aws_role
          do
             if [[ -z "$aws_role" ]]; then
             echo "Null role."
             echo "*****BREAK HERE******"
             break
          fi
          echo "Debug statement"
          echo "***********************************************************************************************************************************************"
          printf "This is the role name: %s\\nThis is the user name: %s\\nThis is the group: %s\\nand this is the account: %s\\n*"  "$aws_role" "$aws_user_name" "$aws_user_group" "$aws_key"
          echo "***********************************************************************************************************************************************"
          **** some more code ****
         done  <<< "${aws_roles[@]}"
    done <<< "${aws_groups[@]}"
   done < "$aws_env_list"  3< "$aws_account_numbers"
 done < "$aws_users_all"
```

What you see here is debug code, as I'm building the script.

I'd appreciate if you could clear up what break is breaking out of, and if it's better to use continue here instead.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` and `continue` only operate on loops, not `if`. This is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002e):

> `break [n]`
>       Exit from within a `for`, `while`, `until`, or `select` loop.  If `n` is specified, break `n` levels.
>
> `continue [n]`
>       Resume  the  next  iteration  of  the  enclosing `for`, `while`, `until`, or `select` loop.  If `n` is specified, resume at the `n`th
>                 enclosing loop.

Comment: Why don't people read documentation before asking questions that are obviously going to be answered there?